# Dihedral groups and normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Consider 
$D_8$ ={$1,r, r^2, r^3,b,br,br^2,br^3$} and the subgroup, $H$={$1,r^2$} and $K$={$b$} of $D_8$

I really need some help with these particular problems.

Show that $H\lhd$$D_8$, but $K$$\ntriangleleft$$D_8$.

show that $HK\lhd$$D_8$.

Any thoughts or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint : $br^i = r^{4-i}b$.

Answer (score 1):

The [theorem](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Center_is_Normal_Subgroup) states that:

> The center $Z(G)$ of any group G is a normal subgroup of G which is abelian.

If $H \lhd D_s$, then this means that for any $d \in D_s$, $Hd = dH$.  Using tetori's hint ($br^{i} = r^{4 - i}b$), verify that the product of any element in $H$ and any element in $d$ is commutative.  If $K \not\lhd D_s$, then you need to find an element $d \in D_s$ and show that $bd \neq db$.

The second part of the problem is similar to the first.  First, you need to multiply each of the elements from $\{1, r^{2}\}$ by $b \in K$.  Then, show that $HK \lhd D_s$, following the method I told you in the second paragraph.

Those are the keys you need to know when solving that type of problem.